# Idioms in Imagine Dragons' "Thunder": "Just a young gun with a quick fuse"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases, informal-language

Imagine Dragons' "Thunder" starts with a confusing verse where the singer speaks the time he was:

> **Just a young gun with a quick fuse**
>
> I was uptight, wanna let loose

The closest meaning I could find is "young passionate/labile leader". Is that the meaning intended by the writer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "young gun" means a "young **gunslinger**", q.v. the movie titled "Young Guns", or "young **tough**", q.v. the hip hop artist duo "Young Gunz".  It does not connote leadership at all, rather being a belligerent, rules-flaunting young man, a **hoodlum** who uses violence to get what he wants, and is generally defiant, hostile, aggressive, spoiling for a fight.

"Just a young gun with a quick fuse" describes a young man with "a chip on his shoulder" (idiom) who is constantly about to explode in violence at the least provocation.

However!  Note that in the larger context of the song, this is meant allegorically.  There's a rhetorical tradition in 20th and now 21st century Western popular music of comparing *artistic ambition* to violence, both in talking *about* music (e.g. "The British Invasion") and within lyrics.  The singer is bragging about his musical career: he is bragging that he has become a conquering hero of music, where once he was just a punk on the street with big dreams and willingness to rumble.

Answer (score 0):

my answer would be that your young and a capable leader. but the part where is says:"i was uptight, wanna let loose" would mean you were finding it hard and you wanted to let it go and get the negativity out. However. that may not be the case. it could mean something completely different.

Answer (score -1):

“Just a young gun with a quick fuse”
In my mind interprets to:
I was a young kid with a short temper
“I was up tight, want to let loose”
In my mind interprets to:
I was a dick, I need to chill out and humble myself.